# Swift SKEmitter Node - BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted

Tags: swift, ios8

I am currently trying to improve my swift sprite kit game. I have an issue where i get the dreaded "BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted" message.

It happens when my bosses start spawning or shoot their weapons. They have an SKEmitter node for their engines and weapons. All bosses and weapons are in their own SKSpriteNode class with boiler plate zPosition, physics body etc code and with the following particle code.

```
let engineParticles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Boss1Thruster.sks")

engineParticles.zPosition = 15
engineParticles.position = CGPointMake(0, -50)
var particleEffects = SKEffectNode() //blends better with background like this
particleEffects.addChild(engineParticles)
addChild(particleEffects)
```

The same for the weapon particles

```
let weaponParticles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Boss1WeaponThruster.sks")    

particles.zPosition = 15
particles.position = CGPointMake(+20, 0)
var particleEffects = SKEffectNode() // blends better this way
particleEffects.addChild(particles)
addChild(particleEffects)
```

The boss(es) spawn offscreen and than come into the scene and do their routine via SKActions. 
This message only happens once for the first particle effect that comes up, than it works fine for the rest of the boss fight. The game doesn't crash when the error message happens but I do get a 1 sec stutter which is annoying. I tried preloading the particles right in the beginning of my game but that didn't make a difference.

Any suggestions why this is happening and what could I do to fix that?
Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a xCode bug using SKEffectNode. I was having other problems as well with SKEffectNode where they would not render SKEmitter children using ios 9 so I am not sure if it is fixed with ios 10.